# What is the generating algorithm for the "komb" instances found on satcompetition.org?

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat, constraint-satisfaction

For the 2017 and 2018 Random SAT Tracks of the SAT Competition ran by the  International Conference on Theory and Applications of Satisfiability Testing there are small, yet difficult, random 3-SAT problems with planted solutions labeled "barthel," "qhid," and "komb." I have been able to determine that "barthel" is referring to [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.188701) procedure, and "qhid" is referring to [this](https://www.jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10484) procedure. The "komb" instances may refer to [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X15000816) procedure, based on the references given in the article [here](https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/164630/sc2016_proceedings.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) on pages 60-62. Note on page 61, in the first sentence of section "Our Approach," 3 references are given, namely, the first 3 references given above. Can anyone confirm the procedure for generating the "komb" instances in the SAT Competitions? (See [satcompetition.org](http://www.satcompetition.org) for more details.)

Comment: the authors should try to make it fully clear in their paper/ documentation & ideally provide source code but alas such care is not always taken. consider emailing them.